# Change format of Telerik DateTimePicker's TimePicker control

Tags: telerik, datetimepicker, telerik-mvc

Per the instructions [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-datetimepicker-configuration.html#Format), I have changed the format of my DateTimePicker to use HH for the date format. And yet, the little clock icon to the right of the textbox still displays the choices in terms of AM and PM. Does anyone know if there is a way to force that to use the same time format?

My current code:

```
@( Html.Telerik().DateTimePicker()
          .Name("DateTimePicker")
          .Value(DateTime.Now)
          .Format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "ui-widget" })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I have been able to test, the AM/PM display relies more on kendo.culture than on the DateTimePicker format.

If I am using the format you provide : ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") with the default culture, I am getting the same display as you get.

But for example if I specify french culture using this simple line : 
" kendo.culture('fr') "
and I specify this same format, I get rid of the AM/PM thing. I do not know what is your whole goal, but I hope this helps.

Comment: This is actually the MVC libraries, not Kendo, but I will see if there is something analagous.

Comment: Oh ok I did not notice you where using mvc libraries, my bad. Good luck with that though!